# MongoDB - search GridFS file contents by string

Tags: php, mongodb, search, gridfs

I am planning to upload user's word documents in MongoDB using GridFS. I have to implement following functionality.

When admin type a string and hit search in administration app, i have to list all word documents where the contents contain the search string. I have to search across all user's documents.

Is there a way to achieve this in MongoDB? If not, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: @AD7six yes. I want to search file contents. If there is a match in it's content, i have to list that file name.

Comment: Could you extract text and keep it in text search indexed attribute referencing the GridFS doc?

Comment: I think you'll be much better off using a search tool - such as elastic search, rather than looking directly in mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB the best you can do is a binary match of your search phrase against the contents in GridFS, but in Word documents you will probably not find this phrase as it's likely compressed.

I think you would be much better off using a dedicated search solution such as Solr.  Solr even allows you to extract text from Word documents and allows you to search for any sort of phrase in a quite complete search language. Have a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler for dealing with Word documents f.e.